# Eevee Render looks WAY DIFFERENT than Viewport Render

Tags: rendering, objects, 3d-view, eevee-render-engine

That's pretty much my whole question. I've followed various tutorials on rendering and nothing seems to change. But something is clearly very messed up.

Here's my screen capture of the Viewport Render. Pretty great.

[image]

And here's my actual render...
[image]

The totally black areas seem to be the JPG filling in transparent space with black. Here's a screen cap again, before I save the image from the Render.

[image]

It almost looks as if its loading some objects, and then entirely forgetting others. Except that the eyeballs on the head are one object with the head, but have also vanished. Help?

Comment: Are you using compositor? If not, please share simplified blend, just with one object that still produce issue in render via https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com